# Google Clode Datastore Client Library creating an entity

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working through some documentation for the google cloud datastore API

Namely https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html
and 
https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/entity.html#Entity

Using both sources I've created the following. I'm extremely confused by client.key(), namely the 1234 and namespace. My datastore shows the keys which seems to be a random? unique number and I have not seen any reference to a namespace. Why is this code sample specifying an integer and a namespace? Is there a better way to generate a key or can these two parameters be safely omitted?

```
    from google.cloud import datastore
    client = datastore.Client()
    key = client.key('Collection', 1234, namespace='_Doctest')
    entity = datastore.Entity(key=key)
    entity['property'] = 'value'
    client.put(entity)
```

[image: key description]

Answer (score 1):

I usually create keys directly without the namespace, just using the Entity kind and let datastore do the rest (*you could specify an ID as well, but it's optional*) this way you are creating an entity with a *partial* key (specifying only the kind) and once you **`put`** the entity in the datastore, the entity key is updated with an ID, to be a complete key (*now has kind and ID*)

```
key = client.key('Collection') # create partial key <Key('Collection')>
entity = datastore.Entity(key=key) # create entity using the partial key
entity['property'] = 'value'
client.put(entity)

# Print the full key <Key('Collection', 5293786145123) project=project-id>
print(f"Entity key = {entity.key}")
```

*Note*: you can also create a key with parent (*Entity Group*) by adding the parent key to the new entity **key assignment** in the first line

```
key = client.key('Collection', parent=<parent_key>)
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm running  key = datastore_client.key('Collection') google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Key path element must not be incomplete: [Collection: ]
I think there a few concepts I need to look into but should the .key() be creating new key for use in the Collection?

Comment: I posted as a different question (Thinking it is?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620409/key-path-element-must-be-complete?noredirect=1#comment97934362_55620409